# How to implement Category, SubCategory and Product in django

Tags: django

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_categories():
        return Category.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1 )
```

How can I now add subcategory to this heirarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assuming that one category can have more than one subcategory and one subcategory can be related to more than one category.

One way(**messy**) is creating three tables(hope you can see the relationship),

```
   class Category(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
        @staticmethod
        def get_all_categories():
            return Category.objects.all()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class SubCategory(models.Model):
        name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
        categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    
    
    class Products(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        category= models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory)
```

Another way(**convenient**) is relating to itself, [ManyToManyField.symmetrical](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) This is the best way.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sub_categories = models.ManyToManyField("self")

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_categories():
        return Category.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category= models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

If you don't specify a related_name, Django automatically creates one using the name of your model with the suffix `_set`. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) has more details

Comment: What is the best way ? 3 tables or just. 1 table?

Comment: Actually, it has two tables. For the given context, the `recursive relationship` approach is the best way(assuming the subcategory entity has no additional attributes). `Categories` and `SubCategories` the same thing

Comment: I have used the messy way, 3 tables

Comment: The querying process will get tedious

Answer (score 2):

Use mptt model is the best option to work on this use case

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", null=True, blank=True, related_name="children", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    background_image = VersatileImageField(
        upload_to="category-backgrounds", blank=True, null=True
    )
    background_image_alt = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    category_icon = models.FileField(upload_to="category-icons", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = TreeManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    weight = models.FloatField(default=0)
    length = models.FloatField(default=0)
    width = models.FloatField(default=0)
    height = models.FloatField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    @property
    def get_featured_image(self):
        image = self.images.filter(is_featured=True).first()
        return image.image.url if image else None

    @property
    def get_price(self):
        if self.discounted_price:
            return self.discounted_price
        return self.price
```

[django mptt docs](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

For reference

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the model itself using `'self'`, e.g.:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', ...)
```

Depending on your needs, if your sub-categories can have only one parent, then you can do:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', related_name='sub_categories',
         on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
```

But if your sub-categories can have more than one parent category, then you can reference them using many-to-many relation:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sub_categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', related_name='parent_categories',
    )
```

Comment: I would also suggest this, since this reduces mess and can be scaled further.